# string .replace() Javascript function on mobile not working

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a piece of code to do some google analytics. It looks like this:

```
$(function () { 
    $('.plan-choose-btn a').bind('click', function(e) {
        //ga load image
        <% String myaccGAEventUrl = trackGoogleAnalyticsEvent(request, "MO-22651379-1", "calltoaction", "buy", "PLC_HOLDER"); %>
        var action = '<%=myaccGAEventUrl%>';
        var hr = $(this).attr('href');
        var bundle = hr.split("id=")[1].split("&")[0];
        action = action.replace("PLC_HOLDER", bundle);
        $('body').append('<img src="'+action+'" width="1" height="1" />');
    });
});
```

If I debug this in a desktop browser I can see that the variable "action" gets updated with the placeholder text replaced with the proper value. But I see on my GA dashboard that this is not happening on mobile, given that I see lots of "PLC_HOLDER" event labels.

Is it possible that the string .replace() function is not working properly on the phone?

Comment: Try `action.replace(/PLC_HOLDER/, bundle);`

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` function was introduced in [JavaScript 1.2](http://web.archive.org/web/19990210100149/http://developer.netscape.com/docs/manuals/communicator/jsguide/restring.htm#1005652), which has been around since 1997.  It's always a possibility that certain older devices (read: browsers) might not fully support certain features of JavaScript.

I would check in Google Analytics to see what devices/browsers are letting the `PLC_HOLDER` string through, which could potentially give you an indication of whether you need to change your production code to use something other than the `replace` function to handle these devices, or if you can safely ignore those devices.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looking on GA I can see is coming from the US (we are in New Zealand). And seeing three different browsers for it: DoCoMo, Samsung-sgh-e250 and Googlebot. Two domains: googlebot and unknown. Could it be some sort of bot?